# How do I rename bundles generated with ng serve of Angular 13?

Tags: angular, rename, serve, bundles

I need to rename bundles generated post `ng serve` of Angular Application.
Currently, the bundles are:

```
vendor.js             
polyfills.js          
styles.css
styles.js 
main.js               
runtime.js
```

I need to rename these files:

```
vendor-<name_application>.js
polyfills-<name_application>.js          
styles-<name_application>.css
styles-<name_application>.js 
main-<name_application>.js               
runtime-<name_application>.js
```

Is it possible?

Comment: first, you should build in production mode: `ng build --prod` that will add a hash string to the name of your built files; you shouldn't, but you can easily change the names of these files as they are only referenced by the built `index.html` file (as long as you change the name references also in this file)

Comment: I need to change names of bundles generated with ```ng serve```

Comment: would you be running `ng serve` out of your dev environment?

Comment: Why? Simply, I execute ng serve on my local machine, to test and debug my Angular Web Application.

Comment: you would be better off ticking the "disable cache" option the devtools have (all mainstream browsers have it)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `--named-chunks` argument or webpack plugin.

check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6700).

Comment: Unfortunately, the option ```--named-chunks``` is Unknown for ```ng serve``` command. My target is change name of bundles generated with command  ```ng serve ```, not  ```ng build ```. I'm using Angular 13.